# Is it safe to play League of Legends when there are files detected as viruses by virustotal.com?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm from Vietnam and started to play League of Legends which I have downloaded from the [official site here for the Vietnamese version](http://lienminh.garena.vn).

Viruses were detected when I ran a virus-scan on the files via [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/).

So my question is, should I run the game when the virus-scan reports viruses?

1. [FileLoader.dll](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5b6e23e3064da67471fe3b41cd41a0ebd5c302928972f3347fd97999bea2422f/analysis/1381269380/)
2. [launcher.maestro.dll](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ee8ff2a948b198a47f6fcd79fed6021f657fe75e175963203168ef88fd7a8834/analysis/1445458282/)
3. [CRiotLauncherElevateCOM.dll](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7812d46b43eb93f8d092a577e4fe6330c0875030977e819b16b4674d301ffb16/analysis/1401766156/)
4. [LolClient.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/87b505e2a820d9631da0c4b885a81364686cd514d22e681a5c9920e8ad036ab8/analysis/1444728174/)
5. [LolClient.swf](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/4f0ef412a61c53f49c781158431e81cfc5aad61e65357dfdff2c82e6140fae92/analysis/1445519715/)

The same virus results apply for the English version of LoL - [results available here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240845/is-it-safe-to-play-league-of-legends).

Comment: I don't normally use websites to search for viruses, as they can be untrustworthy, I recommend downloading a program like Malwarebytes Anti-Malware to search for viruses/.PUPs

Comment: Maybe not, but I would still trust an antivirus program better than a website, maybe it's just me

Comment: @TrapHappy [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirusTotal) is saying fine things about it. I'd still use a standalone antivirus program, like Norton, or the likes.

Comment: I second Malwarebytes Anti-Malware. It's very good software and free to boot, I've recovered several machines using it.

Comment: Some anti virus software has a publisher registry and will flag executable files downloaded from a source that isn't in their registry. Not necessarily your problem, but something to watch out for.

Comment: I agree, you should use a program instead of a website

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster Well, virustotal.com is a service that run tens of programs as you suggestion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @NamGVU ah, I didn't know that. I shouldn't assume...

Comment: @NamGVU According to them. Frankly I wouldn't trust any website on the global Internet to guarentee my computer's security. The webmaster could be doing anything without your knowledge; you have no way of guarenteeing that it is a legitimate or reliable service, the same way you have no way of knowing your League of Legends files aren't infected unless you download from the official website (and even then there is a minute chance that their security was compromised and someone placed a virus there instead).

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Not sure what you mean after all :(

Comment: Guys! Chillax; virustotal is a service where you upload file, or checksum of the file; and then virustotal checks this file/checksum against 30-40 virus databases from vendors like ESET, AVG... etcetera. So there is no harm what so ever (only UPLOAD). I myself use virustotal to make sure when I download any kind of file from not known source; I don't own any other anti-virus program; and have no issues since 2008 (win xp pro) or 2010 (laptop - win 7 pro). I personally trust vendors like Kaspersky, ESET, AVG if all 3 are green then file should be fine.

Comment: @Kyslik Totally agree with you.

Comment: Today scanning, 201602.13, only found two viruses 1) FileLoader.dll https://goo.gl/AlJp4A, 2) HookAPI.dll https://goo.gl/a83aCR

Answer (score 14):

The files are only pinging as bad on one or two anti-virus programs and not on any of the more reputable ones. Anti-virus software isn't perfect and false positives happen.

It is far more likely that one anti-virus program is wrong about it being a virus than it is that almost all of them are. The files are probably safe.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I should point out that in some cases sites like VirusTotal will not be correct.  I will post a link to an article that goes over some of the information, but AV companies will mark files as malicious (due to false-positives or bad practices).  http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/08/report-claims-kaspersky-faked-malware-to-trip-up-competitors-products/

Comment: _"It is far more likely that one anti-virus program is wrong about it being a virus than it is that almost all of them are."_ This statement is true.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Just like Marcks said, i would agree with that statement rather than to say it's 100% false.  I would reword that to say it's not always true, otherwise your sentence sounds more like you are saying AV companies are never wrong.  Think of it this way, he is saying the probability of 1 AV being wrong is much greater than 20 different AV programs being wrong.  That implies 1 AV can have a false-positive and 19 other AV programs say the file is safe.

Answer (score 4):

As most of the antiviruses did not find anything harmful in the files, I would say, the remaining one may be a false alarm. I do not trust those antiviruses either. I would say since you downloaded the game from the official site and those alarm raising antiviruses are not really trustworthy(IMO), feel free to play your game.

Answer (score 3):

To me, this sounds like a wrong alert. Or you downloaded something from the wrong source. Just for safety, I'd delete the game completely and redownload it from the OFFICIAL website. Riot wouldn't place any viruses in their games themselves, but maybe you tried to download a hack or something. These are usually viruses.

Note: Even if you delete it, if there was a virus, just deleting the game probably won't solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering the question :

> So my question is, should I run the game when the virus-scan reports viruses?

If you're sure that your machine is infected, there are two possibilities :

1. Your machine infected before you login to LoL : You shouldn't login any of your game/online accounts, the malware can be a [Keylogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging#Software-based_keyloggers) .
2. Your machine infected after you login to LoL : The malware can listen your connection and send the connection information to the attacker. You may trust LoL itself, because in login phase your LoL username/password is **possibly** going over [encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) connection. And after login, periodic 'login check' mechanism will check you through an encrypted connection. But still encrypted packets may be stripped. But this gets harder as your password gets stronger.

**If you trust LoL you should keep your password strong.**

And this is kinda old(2012), but worth to look at. LoL's security [announcement](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=724516) .

Comment: Well, I scan the file right after I donwload the client i.e. before I execute anything.

Comment: I think the trojan/virus results are false-positive as others' said. These are safe files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you downloaded from the wrong place.

Based on information from [this thread](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=641740).  The official downloads are actually [here](http://lol.garena.com/download).

Comment: They're both official sites on the same domain name. You just linked the English one whereas OP linked the Vietnamese language site.

Comment: Thanks Nelson. As @Studoku said, I download from Vietnamese sister site of LoL.

Comment: I'll try the client from English version one more time though.

Comment: I download from here http://lol.garena.com/download. Though after downloaded, I don't know where the files are - asked as here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240616/where-are-league-of-legend-files-located-after-download

Comment: I scanned the English version of LoL and the it seems to be the same i.e. viruses detected. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240845/is-it-safe-to-play-league-of-legends