# Where are the whole League of Legend installation files/caches located after download?

Tags: league-of-legends

A few [google search of mine](https://www.google.com/search?q=League%20of%20Legend%20files%20located%20after%20download%3F&oq=League%20of%20Legend%20files%20located%20after%20download%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61.311j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) came up with these [results #1,](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1076614) [#2](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=629218) though it's not helpful to me on my Windows 7 PC.

So, where are the downloaded files? I download from official site [here](http://lol.garena.com/download).

p.s.

The `starter` installation file `LoL_Install_151015.exe` is of course easily accessed via the web browser in Dowloads section - what I'm asking is the files that are then downloaded by this `starter`.

When starter is run, it will download about 2-3 gigabytes more, and when done, executing the starter will open the LoL game installation dialog as below snapshot. Where are those `later-downloaded` files location?

** Update **

As @Aequitas recommended below, I use `Search Everything`, and see one DataStore.edb which is the most prominent candidate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What results #1 2 and 3? why aren't they helpful to you?

Comment: Is this off topic? I feel like this is a question about the Windows file system, not League of Legends.

Comment: @nukeforum No, it is not off-topic. My question is about LoL installation file location.

Comment: @Aequitas I've updated my question to provide my missed links.

Comment: Why do you want to know where those files? they'll likely be deleted after installation and you probably won't be able to open them even if you copy them or prevent deletion.

Comment: I need to scan them for viruses via virustotal.com as discussed here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/240564/3385

Comment: @NamGVU if you're downloading the client from the official site it'll be fine. Also scanning the installer itself will likely be fine, also run a scan after installation and ensure that you have your active scanner on while it's installing. There's no real need to run a specific scan on the installer files. The installer itself will have to have malware in order to download more malicious software.

Comment: would the files not just be in C:\Riot Games\ or C:\Program Files (x86)\Riot Games\?

Comment: @TrapHappy That is installed path - I asked for the installation package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files that you are referring to will be downloaded to a temporary folder of which it's location will be different depending on several things particularly your operating system.

Even on the same computer if you do the installation twice, the files will likely be downloaded to different locations.

Some common temp locations which the Garena LoL installer may use for these files are:

- C:\Windows\Temp
- C:\Users\ComputerName\AppData\Local\Temp
- C:\Temp
- C:\tmp

---

In order to find the files that the installer downloads you can use a program called **[Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)**.

Once installed click on the **Date Modified** tab in order to sort every file on your computer, so that the most recently created/modified files are shown on top. Note: the first time you click "Date Modified" will take a considerable amount of time, you can see that it's working by the *Sorting...* in the bottom left.

Once you've sorted it in this way, begin installation and the files that the installer creates/downloads will be shown near the top of this list. Once you identify the files you are interested in just look at the *Path* tab, or you can right click on the file and select *Open Path* which will open the folder that that file is in.

Comment: Great idea. I'll try and back to you later.

Comment: I'll tried `Search Everything` and found one candidate is the `DataStore.edb` file as snapshot here http://i.stack.imgur.com/FfTCM.png
I don't know if it is right.

Comment: @NamGVU why not? If that's what showed up when you installed it then those are what you're looking for. Everything will show every single file that gets modified so it HAS to be one of the ones near the top of the list once sorted by most recently modified. DataStore is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @NamGVU also you should close chrome when you do this because that modifies files constantly and will make it harder to determine what the installer is doing. Better to close as many things as possible when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox and Chrome you can push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> in order to open up *Downloads*.

From here on Chrome you can click *Show in folder* on the League of Legends installer and the folder where you downloaded it to will open up. [image: Chrome Download List]

In Firefox you can right click the files and select *Open containing folder* to achieve the same thing, or click the icon of the folder next to the download.
[image: Firefox Download List]

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway. I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for the installer location, he's looking for the game cache. (The stuff the installer puts its stuff, which should be in the LoL install folder somewhere, I think)

Comment: @aytimothy he's edited his question, so i know that now

Comment: Yeah, you're surely right ^^ Thanks a lot @Aequitas