# Where, and in what format, are the in-game assets (sounds, models, etc.) stored for League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/240616/133336), but that does not appear to contain the answer I need.

Where can I find the actual in-game assets used by League of Legends? I was able to find the champion select sounds in `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\0.0.1.215\deploy\assets\sounds\en_US\champions`, but where are the actual in game sounds (or the models, for that matter)?

I'd like to be able to replace some of those sounds with blanks so that I don't have to listen to as many character quips.

Answer (score 1):

For assets images in general, Riot has released them. https://github.com/RiotAPI/Riot-Games-API-Developer-Assets

For audio, I'm gonna guess they are all compiled, and can't really be extracted except if you can find a way to decompile the game. Which is very hard to do.