# Can I get banned for using LSI (League Summoner Information)?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been using LSI for about a week, what this program allows me to do is:

- Edit what champions I get when I type in the search bar.
- In game allows me to view all the damage i took from every source.
- Allows me to open a side window with viewable information to every player's rank, runes, masteries and so forth.
- Allows me to stop league audio from resetting after a patch. (Thank God for this!)

These are the main features, i was wondering, can i get banned for using this? Because it isn't giving me an unfair gameplay advantage over the enemy team, nor any information i can't obtain from other websites, like lolking.net and such

Comment: 'Allows me to open a side window with viewable information to every player's rank, runes, masteries and so forth.' Sounds like it is giving you a more detailed breakdown, that is easier to see, than the in game alternative. therefore, it is giving you an advantage. Whether there would be a repercussion, unlikely but possible.

Comment: the lol board would be the right place to ask this, also search on there if you find anything regarding lsi. For now i doubt they really ban anyone for only that.

Comment: @nickson104 yet these advantages could also be gained by just going to lolskill, lolking or something else, there are a lot of sites that also provide the same ammount of information, this just takes the need to go to a browser just a click of a button to access it

Comment: @Magmagod I know, but I don't believe that Riot endorse these websites, but again how can they know your using them, its no problem really

Comment: I also don't believe believe Riot endorse them, but they also can't stop us from really using them without most likely banning (either temporarily or permanently) almost the entire community (come on, when you had a low rank you would check out what rank you were going to play against)

Comment: @Magmagod: such tools obvisious are endorsed, otherwise riot just would change the itnerface those pages are accesing the informations from.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Here's a great recent thread on the matter that got a Riot Seal of Approval<sup>TM</sup>.](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/player-behavior-moderation/5dmkJinG-3rd-party-applicationsmodifications-whats-allowed-and-what-isnt?comment=0002)

> Riot Sargonas (NA) - 5 months ago
>
> Totally fine to use it. We worked with LSI directly to ensure that
>   their features fit within our 3rd party guidelines.

LSI is totally allowed to be used. (for now)

Comment: Well, just scanned and detected 02 viruses from Google VirusTotal https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5f02a045492ce4bce833292f423c3693aca1b52cbd0bfc07865d17617d7fcf3c/analysis/1456673590/

Comment: Hi @NamGVU, I don't think that results from 2/55 virus scanners can really be the final consensus on whether it's a virus, especially since they don't agree on the result. Either way, its status as having the Riot "ok" is not dictated by whether it passes one virus scan or another, but on the functionality of the software in relation to League.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. About relation with Riot, the game itself contains viruses too http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/240562/3385

Comment: I just want to make sure things are clear and we play a clear game. Hope the two producers would not treat us as virus seeder.

Comment: @NamGVU Let me make myself perfectly clear. A virus scan performed by 52 different scanners where only one or two scanners come back with a positive result is not even remotely conclusive. Especially when the AVs throwing positive results **don't even agree on the result**. You can't automatically assume every little thing is true. Tens of millions of people play this game every day. You think if there was a virus to be found, it wouldn't be massively publicly known and the software be publicly reviled for including malware/viruses? Don't spread misinformation.

Comment: Furthermore, this discussion has literally nothing to do with the topic. If you want to bring something like this up, go to the League of Legends forums or the LSI forums. You're not doing anyone any good with unrelated cross-talk.

Comment: Nice talk. Sorry for not being contributive to your info.

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe eventually, but probably not.**

Strictly speaking, it is a third party program, so Riot can't approve it. Third party programs are updated all the time and Riot doesn't have any control over what changes are made, so they can't explicitly give the OK to any of them. From a [recent post on the forums](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/miscellaneous/5kx4F7VE-reminder-third-party-applications?comment=00000001):

> We will not be maintaining a list of applications that might be approved or denied, because honestly, we’re just not ever going to be able to continually audit every service or function for player security, especially in this ecosystem where devs so frequently improve and expand their apps. And just to clarify, Curse is not "100% approved" specifically either, though it is okay to use. We only spoke about it specifically by name to clear up confusion around the fact we did initially prohibit its use, but we want to make sure it's clear that it is not "100% approved" as we do not make that statement about any particular app.

However, in this specific case it's worth noting that the people working on LSI stay connected very closely with Riot to make sure that their program doesn't violate the Terms of Service and won't fire false flags for the methods Riot uses to detect scripts and the like. In addition, the player ranking information is freely available on several websites for the same reason LSI can find it: Riot has a public-facing API, which wouldn't offer this info if they didn't want it to, especially given how long it's been up and how established some of these sites/programs are.

So if in the future changes are made to LSI without consulting Riot, it's possible that using the program will be a bannable offense. But at the moment it seems that's not the case.

Comment: Check the accepted answer, riot approved it.

Comment: @ardaozkal Directly quoted from the accepted answer's link: "Also, naturally, we can never officially condone or promote the use of any third party tool, as we can never guarantee your game stability or safety in doing so." They officially approve of *things that programs do*, not programs themselves--although they've been very inconsistent about how they say so.

Comment: "So if in the future changes are made to LSI without consulting Riot, it's possible that using the program will be a bannable offense. But at the moment it seems that's not the case." Really really important point, thanks for getting that one out here.

Comment: While I feel nukeforum's answer is better, this answer is still super useful. Like on a calculus test, the answer is a lot of times less important than how the answer is derived.